# Find text in string in PHP

Tags: php, string

This should be pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere on how to do it.
I have a string in PHP.  That string might contain within it somewhere the substring ":ERROR:".  I need to find if it has that string. `strpos()` has worked perfectly up to this point, until today when ":ERROR:" was the first item in the string, so `strpos()` returned `0`, so the program kept running thinking it had no error.

I don't need to replace the string, or do any manipulation to it, I just need a simple `true/false` answer to "does :ERROR: exist in the string?"

Comment: its always better to do a strict comparison in PHP whenever available.  This equilavence of "", 0, false, etc. can be a good source of unexpected errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP Manual on [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

```
if (strpos($myString, ":ERROR:") !== FALSE) {
  // Error!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) returns `false` when the string is not found, so check for `false` instead of making an implicit condition.

```
if(strpos($string, ':ERROR:') !== false) {
    // Do something...
}
```

---

As Anurag said in the comments, with functions like these it's always best to do a strict comparison (`===` instead of just leaving out the operator or using `==`) because that's a common source of bugs, especially in PHP, where many functions can return values of different types.

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the `strpos()` problems of not checking with a strict type operator by using the lesser known [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($string, ':ERROR:') !== false){
    //found ':ERROR:' in string
}
```

> > *"[strpos()] [r]eturns the position as an integer. If needle is not found, strpos() will return boolean FALSE."*
> >     http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

If the position is 0, then merely using == or != will evaluate 0 and false as equivalent. So use === or !== to avoid type coercion.