# How to search array for specific word with strpos

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all, strpos

```
$data = "
usera: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy.
userb: eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam.
userc:voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet.";

preg_match_all("/(.*:)/", $data, $why1);
array_walk_recursive($why1, function($value) use (&$why2) {
    $why2[] = $value;
});
$why3 = array_unique($why2);
$why4 = array_values($why3);

preg_match_all("/(.*.)/", $data, $info);
array_walk_recursive($info, function($value) use (&$shrink) {
    $shrink[] = $value;
});
$brss = array_unique($array_flat);
$arss = array_values($brss);

for($i=0;$i < count($brss); $i++){

$usera = "$why4[0]";
$userb = "$why4[1]";
$userc = "$why4[2]";
$userd = "$why4[3]";

if (strpos($brss[i], $usera) !== false) 

// How can I
{echo "true";}
// ?

// I only get false

else {echo "false";}

}
```

How to get a true in searching my array by asking a specific word with strpos?

How can I `echo "true";`?

Comment: What do you want to match with `.*.`? You use `array_walk_recursive` several times and a `for` loop to deal with arrays, you should try to rewrite your code using only `foreach`.

Comment: I wanted to match for name: bla bla bla. To geht extly matches until the . I used http://www.phpliveregex.com to geht the correct regex.

Comment: To figure a literal `.` (a dot) in a regex, you need to escape it with a backslash `\.` otherwise it means any character except a newline (this is one of the reasons why it seems to work). Other thing, `.*` doesn't stop at the first dot but at the last dot of the line. To stop at the first dot you need to use a non-greedy quantifier `.*?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text in string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099032/find-text-in-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($brss[**$i**],$usera)!==false) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

Does it.